# Redeclare a typedef in C

Tags: c, scope, declaration, typedef, extern

I am reading the book *The C programming Language* by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie.

At A.8.9 section the books sais:

> Typedef names may be redeclared in an inner scope, but a non-empty set of type specifiers must be
>   given. For example, `extern Blockno;` does not redeclare Blockno, but `extern int Blockno;` does.

I am feeling that I understand the `extern Blockno;` but what does it mean the `extern int Blockno;`?

When I am trying to do it I get a compile error and I still don't understand what the book means!

Comment: @Lundin I disagree with statement that there is `extern` in the code for it being bad...

Comment: @Lundin According to what I have read at the moment, it is good to be found at header files. Apart from that how the linkers will understand that I am talking for the same variable across different files?

Comment: @Lundin do you mean that you are against using global variables ?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It can either be used for spaghetti programming purposes with global variables, in which case it is 100% bad. Or it can be used for needlessly explicit function declarations, in which case it is just superfluous. The only somewhat valid use-cases are `extern const` (still questionable) and sharing register maps of embedded systems across files (ok).

Comment: @LiTTle Don't talk to the same variable across files. Use setter/getter functions.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Among other bad uses of `extern`, yes. The other bad use being `extern void func (void);` which is about as meaningful as writing `auto int x;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He means that a typedef name can be redeclared. For example it can be a variable name provided that the redeclaration occurred in an inner scope.

He points that such a declaration of a variable

```
extern Blockno;
```

is incorrect. A variable should have a type specifier that is a declaration should specify which type the declared entity has. Early the type int used as a default type.

So it will be correctly to write to declare an object of the type int like

```
extern int Blockno;
```

that is this declaration introduces in a local scope the variable `Blockno` of the type int. The storage class specifier means that this declaration refers to already defined object `Blockno` with either the external or internal linkage.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Int = 10;

int main(void) 
{
    typedef int Int;

    {

        extern int Int;

        printf( "Int = %d\n", Int );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Int = 10
```

The declaration at block scope

```
extern int Int;
```

hides the typedef name `Int` declared in the outer scope and refers to the declaration

```
int Int = 10;
```

in the global scope.

Comment: Much more clear than the book writings! Is it me or is it really bad to create this type of "tricks" (same name, different purpose) in the code? I still find it weird in the eye!

Comment: @LiTTle In general you should avoid using global variables. However if they are used then sometimes you need to introduce them in a local scope.